# Continuity after taking a quotient

Tags: general-topology

Let $X,Y$ be topological spaces and let $f:X \to Y$ be continuous.

> When is $\overline{f}: X/U \to Y, [x]\mapsto f(x)$ continuous?

My thoughts:

We replace a part of the space by a point and a point is closed. Well, okay, unless $X$ has a weird topology like the discrete topolology...

But if $X$ is a metric space so that points are closed it seems intuitive that allowable spaces are closed spaces: if we map a closed space to a closed space (=the point) then we do not change the topology and therefore the map remains continuous.

So my conjecture is that $\overline{f}$ is continuous if and only if $U$ is closed.

Comment: So you assume $f$ to be constant on $U$?

Comment: What is $U$? Conditions need to be put on it to ensure the quotient function can even be defined, let alone be continuous.

Comment: If $f$ is indeed constant on $U$, then your function remains continuous no matter how $U$ look likes since $f^{-1}(V)$ for $V\subseteq Y$ open is always saturated hence also open in the quotient space...

Comment: @MattSamuel That's what the question is about.

Comment: @fweth I didn't intend to assume that $f$ was constant on $U$.

Comment: The condition for well-defindness of your function is that $f$ is constant on $U$, otherwise how would you interpret $f([x])$ if $[x]=[y]$ but $f(x)\neq f(y)$?

Answer (score 1):

Whenever you pass from a space $X$ to a quotient space $X/\!\sim\,$ the condition for a map $X/\!\sim\,\to Y$ to be continuous is the composite map $X\to X/\!\sim\,\to Y$ to be continuous. This means that the only obstruction for a continuous map $f:X\to Y$ to induce a continuous map $\bar f:X/\!\sim\,\to Y$ is that $\bar f$ really exists, that is, it is well defined: whenever $x\sim x'$ then $f(x)=f(y)$. In other words, the fibers $f^{-1}(y)$ be *saturated* with respect to the given relation $\sim\,$. In the special case the relation is identifying any given subset to a single point, this saturation means that $f$ is constant on the subset. Other considerations, whether the subset is closed or not, for instance, affect the nature of the quotient space, but not continuity.